# Systematic sampling by FID

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, select-by-attribute

I have a shapefile created by a corn planter. It creates a point for each planting row every second. So a 16-row planter creates 16 points as it goes along the field. As a consequence, a small 30-acre field has over 400,000 points and it's a nightmare to load, not to mention to start any analysis.
The points are created systematically in increasing order. I would like to extract points every Nth observations. For example, to get the center of the planter pass, I would extract the FID=4, and then every 8 observations after that. Any suggestions to do this?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

modulo is quite convenient for this. you can go to the properties of your layer, definition queries, and set

```
MOD("FID"+4,8)=0
```

if you want to create a subset,

you can also use this to select by attribute and export the layer in a new layer, but it is not necessary.

As a remark, your display should go faster with a file geodatabase. 
Also, shapefile FID usually starts at 0, so I'd rather do +3 instead of +4

Comment: Thanks! Your response guided me to the right answer. The formula I ended up using is MOD("FID"+4,8)=0

Comment: thanks for the correction, it was a typo because I started with the Python syntax (%), then I switched to MOD()